# what is order will the functions foo and bar be executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I can't understand In which order will the functions foo and bar be executed?

1- foo and bar will execute in the same time, or 2- foo then bar or 3- bar then foo, I think 1- but I don't sure

```
var res = {};

function foo(results) {
    res.foo = results;
}

function bar(results) {
    res.bar = results;
}

// ajax (..) is some arbitrary function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", foo );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", bar );
```

Comment: If ajax is an async function that uses a callback and `foo` and `bar` are those callbacks then they will be executed in arbitrary order. If you want them to run in sequence you have to either move the 2nd ajax call inside `foo` (old school) or use .then() or await instead (with a promisified version of ajax)

Comment: are you mean  foo then bar

Comment: Like I said: if you *want* to run foo first, you can easily achieve that. So yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You removed the correct answer from your question in your first edit. It's: *"2- We don't know"*

You can't know the order without knowing the implementation (or documentation) of `ajax`. The order could even change between different runs.

Here is an example:

```js
function ajax(url, fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, Math.random() * 1000);
}

var res = {};

function foo(results) {
    res.foo = results;
    console.log('foo');
}

function bar(results) {
    res.bar = results;
    console.log('bar');
}

// ajax (..) is some arbitrary function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", foo );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", bar );
```

You can run it multiple times and the order changes. Sometimes it's

```
foo
bar
```

and sometimes it's

```
bar
foo
```

but the functions will never be called at the same time.

Comment: I don't used promise, I just want learn  1- foo and bar will execute in the same time, or 2- foo then bar or 3- bar then foo,

Comment: @xh9tlf8d82 You can't know without more information about `ajax`. The correct answer is the option you removed in your edit: _"2- We don't know"_

Answer (score -1):

> foo and bar will execute in the same time

JavaScript generally operates on a single event loop. Unless you farm out processing to a Worker you will *never* have two functions running at the same time.

> 2- foo then bar or 3- bar then foo, I think 1

You haven't shown us the `ajax` function, but **assuming** it makes an HTTP callback and then queues the callback function up to be called once the **complete** HTTP response has arrived:

The order will depend on how quickly the server responds to each of the two different HTTP requests and how long it takes for the browser to receive the response.

For example, `http://some.url.1` *might* cause the server to spend 30 seconds doing a really complete database query before responding, while `http://some.url.2` might do something simple that gets a response after 3ms: In which case `bar` would be added to the queue before `foo` and thus run first.

Answer (score -2):

We can't predict the order of the functions foo & bar. These functions depends on ajax request to an api, so whichever ajax request completes first, it will call the corresponding function.

Note: If you need to do synchronize both the functions together, then you can use a promise method.